# gtsummary's modify_caption function: inserting a soft return for a docx destination

Tags: r

When using gtsummary's *modify_caption* function, I'm able to successfully insert a soft return within the text when the output publishes to RStudio's Viewer by using "< br >":

modify_caption("Table 1 Invertebrate Speciation < br > (Australia)")

(note that I added spaces to < br > so that it is not resolved as HTML in this post); however, how do I insert a soft return if I'm writing the output to a docx file using

|> gtsummary::as_flex_table() |> flextable::save_as_docx(path = "T001 IS - AUS.docx")
?

I tried replacing the < br > with \n, but that does not insert a soft return. Instead, the title of the table in the MS Word document looks like this:

```
       Table 1 Invertebrate Speciation \n (Australia)
```

. I want it to look like this

```
       Table 1 Invertebrate Speciation 
                 (Australia)
```

.

Thanks in advance for your help.

-Bill

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to insert a return in the gtsummary object, insert the "\n" after converting the gtsummary object into a flextable object:

```
|> 
gtsummary::as_flex_table() |> 
flextable::set_caption(as_paragraph(as_chunk("Table 1 Invertebrate Speciation \n (Australia)", italic=FALSE, bold=TRUE)), word_stylename = "Table Caption") |> flextable::save_as_docx(path = "T001 IS - AUS.docx")
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing the dataframe/whatever the original object was